# Delete row UITableView issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am using this code... But it has terminated my application a few times:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //FeedArray is NSMutableArray
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [FeedArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Why is this happening? Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that `[self.tableView endUpdates];` must be in `if{}` block

or `[self.tableView beginUpdates];` must be before `if{}`

Answer (score 0):

I used code like this, and it worked fine:

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
{

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    //Remove the item from the array (i.e. update the data source).
    [self.arrayList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Delete the row from the table.
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```